# How to change coordinates of dynamic markers on google map SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have data from server with coordinates of my markers and that data is dynamic. So next, I must add them to the google map. But after 5 seconds (I have timer) data changes, and I must change my data at marker.
My function:

```
//self.markers.map = nil
self.mapView.clear()
for temp_cord in double_arr {
  self.markers = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(temp_cord[1])!, longitude: Double(temp_cord[2])!))
  self.markers.map = self.mapView
 }
```

If I uncomment `self.markers.map = nil` my markers will duplicate but not delete. So my markers look like cars and then move on the google map.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all pins before plotting new set of pins. Use this following code to remove all pins from your map. It works fine for me

NSObject Class

```
import Foundation
class LocationVO: NSObject {
var L_Latitude: String
var L_Longitude: String
var L_Id: String
var L_PlaceId: String
var L_Reference: String
var L_Name: String
}
```

ViewController

```
func plotPins() {
    mapView_.clear()
    if isCurrentLoc {
        if marker_ == nil {
            marker_ = GMSMarker()
        }
    }
    else {
        marker_ = GMSMarker()
        marker_.userData = locationVO
    }
    var target: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationVO.L_Latitude, locationVO.L_Longitude)
    marker_.position = target
    marker_.title = "Current:"
    var coord: String = "\(latitude) \(longitude)"
    marker_.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    DLog("%f %f", latitude, longitude)
    //    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
    if isCurrentLoc {
        marker_.opacity = 0.0
    }
    marker_.snippet = (coord)
    marker_.map = mapView_
}
```

Thanks, Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I think, your code are work with Apple Maps, I try to create the same function with Google Maps